# Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it is a known property

Tags: angular, typescript, app-route

```
//catgory.component.html
    `<li
    (click)="setCurrentCategory(category)"
    routerLink="/projects/category/{{ category.categoryId }}"
    *ngFor="let category of categories"
    [class]="getCurrentCategoryClass(category)"
  >
    {{ category.categoryName }}
  </li>`
//category.component.ts

     setCurrentCategory(category: Category) {
    this.currentCategory = category;
    console.log(category)

  }
//app-routing.module.ts

    `const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: ProjectComponent },
  { path: 'projects', component: ProjectComponent },
  { path: 'projects/category/:categoryId', component: ProjectComponent },
  {
    path: 'projects/add',
    component: PorjectAddComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginGuard],
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];`
```

Description
I shared the code snippets of the error that I think is caused by the Angular version.
Router Link cannot be reached to the given address.
I am waiting for your help in this matter.
Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAwCH.png)

Comment: Based on the error it seems {{ category.categoryId }} is not set?

Comment: That's what I thought since he's not showing the constructor nor the onInit method. However, it is true that the error is caused because he's not importing the RouterModule. Anyways the code can be improved hugely

Answer (score 0):

Hello that's work for me

```
<a [routerLink]="'yourLink'" ></a>
```

Don't forget to import RouterModule in your ap
module.ts RouterModule.forRoot(routes)

Answer (score -1):

import RouterModule in your module